# default modelbinder uses wrong cultureinfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, cultureinfo

I have multi-language site and each language uses its own cultureinfo.
I tried to set culterinfo with ActionFilterAttribute, but it is fired after modelbinding. 
I also tried global asax BeginRequest but RouteData is not yet available.

So where should set CurrentUICulture to modelbinder would also use cultureinfo needed?

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find what you can/need to override from this great article: [An Introduction to ASP.NET MVC Extensibility](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1358)

You could write a custom MvcRouteHandler:

```
public class LangRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("lang"))
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo(requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString());
            if (culture != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            }
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

And use this routehandler in your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{lang}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", lang = "en", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new LangRouteHandler();
```

Comment: one question though... is it possible to make my custom route handler as default routehandler?

Comment: Don't think so. But if you want to be sure have a look at the source code of the MapRoute extension method in the MVC project, it is open source.